# How can we connect to SQL or other Database using HTML5?

Tags: html

How can we connect to SQL or other Database using HTML5? Am new to HTML5 can any one help me

Comment: Can you extend your question with smaple code and specify your database type etc..

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106740/how-to-connect-with-server-side-database-using-pure-html5

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is a static document, you cannot connect to a database with HTML5, but you can use php or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 drafts used to define a couple of database systems, but they have been broken out into separate specifications ([Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) and [Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)).

These provide databases that are accessible only to the browser though. If you want a shared database (i.e. so that data saved by one user can be accessed by another user visiting the same site) then you need to use a server side database.

The usual ways to communicate with a server side database from the client in a web application are:

- A web application where data is submitted via forms
- A web service accessed using XMLHttpRequest

Comment: the best way to connecting database using javascript...

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete reference here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

However, try to format your questions better, and tell us what did you try, what do you want to achieve.